# parsing html with css selector jsoup

Tags: html, parsing, jsoup

I'm trying to get the value shown in the image below from www.dolarhoy.com [image: Dolar Hoy]

I use jsoup to do thinks like this, but the following code is not working.

```
private static String obtenerCotizacion() throws IOException {
    Document docDolarHoy = Jsoup.connect("http://www.dolarhoy.com").get();

    String dolar= docDolarHoy.select("div.col-md-6.venta > h4 > span").first().text();
    System.out.println("dolarHoy: " + dolar); 

    return dolar;
}
```

}

also probe
String dolar= docDolarHoy.select("body > div.container.body-content > div > div > div.col-md-8 > div.row > div.col-md-6.venta > h4 > span").first().text();

and

String dolar= docDolarHoy.select("div.col-md-6:nth-child(2) > h4:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)").first().text();

this gives me back a empty value.

Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using my browser's developer tools I got the following selector - `div.col-md-6:nth-child(2) > h4:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)`.
If you still don't get it - add the `userAgent` string of your browser to the `get` request, something like -

```
Document docDolarHoy = Jsoup.connect("http://www.dolarhoy.com")
    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0")
    .get();
```

**EDIT**
After some trials the full working code (minus exception handling) is:

```
Public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Document docDolarHoy = Jsoup.connect("http://www.dolarhoy.com")
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0")
            .get();
    String dolar= docDolarHoy.select("div.col-md-6.venta > h4 > span").first().text();
    System.out.println("dolarHoy: " + dolar);
    System.out.println(docDolarHoy.html());     
}
```

And the output:

> dolarHoy: $ 30.84

Comment: this keeps returning an empty value

Comment: public class Main {   
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {  
  Document docDolarHoy = Jsoup.connect("http://www.dolarhoy.com")
       .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0")
       .get();
  String dolar= docDolarHoy.select("div.col-md-6.venta > h4 > span").first().text();
  System.out.println("dolarHoy: " + dolar);   
 }
}

Comment: output: dolarHoy: $ 30.84

Comment: Hi, if a use "dolarhoy.com" it returns Malformed URL: dolarhoy.com and if a use "http://www.dolarhoy.com" it throws nullpointer

Comment: Right, when I've pasted my code as a comment SO changed it. It should be http  :  //  www  . dolarhoy.com without the spaces of course.

Comment: I swear to god it does not work for me, i cant understand why

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178558/discussion-between-mmayer-and-tdg).